# Why doesn't label text change?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

```
def tsk0_start():
status0.configure(text="Running (1)")    
backend.task0(backend.tsk0_arg[0],backend.tsk0_arg[1],backend.tsk0_arg[2],backend.tsk0_arg[3],backend.tsk0_arg[4],backend.tsk0_arg[5],backend.tsk0_arg[6],backend.tsk0_arg[7],backend.tsk0_arg[8],backend.tsk0_arg[9],backend.tsk0_arg[10],backend.tsk0_arg[11],backend.tsk0_arg[12],1)
```

I want to change text but it doesn't work.
I tried changing the positions, but it doesn't seem to work.
Thanks

Comment: The code you posted should work. Can you please tell me more about `task0`? How long does it take to run? Also you know that you can replace that long line with: `backend.task0(*backend.tsk0_arg)`.

Comment: task0 is a function that is being called after filling forms it should take about ~30 sec

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example of your code? Try putting the `task0` call in another thread. Also what do you mean by "*it doesn't work*"? Does your app stop responding?

Comment: It responds just it doesn't change text

Comment: Are you sure `status0` is the correct label? Is something else changing its text? We need to see more of your code to find the mistake.

Comment: If `task0()` takes 30 seconds to run, any changes to the label are going to be delayed for that long - since you're at no point giving Tkinter the chance to process the update.  Try putting something like `root.update_idletasks()` just before the call to `task0()`.

Comment: I set a function that creates status0 taht function runs before task0 and I set global status0 in the function **this answers your first comment**

Comment: like I should put in the end or what?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to us. In addition give a brief explanation to us what your code is supposed to do an how it act different from your expectation. #Voted to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @jasonharper's suggestion, call `root.update_idletasks()` before calling `tsk0_start()`.

Example:

```py
def tsk0_start():
    status0.configure(text="Running (1)")
    root.update_idletasks()
    backend.task0(*backend.tsk0_arg)
```